# How can I create a Menu group after clicking a button?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-menu

What I want to do, is to create a menu with checkeable items like this:

[image]

But just after clicking a button or icon in my main activity, so I can have different menus like this depending on the button which I click. I don't know if this is the right component or what I have to do.

I would just need a sample with a button and after clicking it, it creates this kind of menu with some options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to accomplish this. One way would be to have a `layout` that you want to use for it and use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). This will create this type of look. You will just create the `contentView` to go inside it.

Another way, especially if you need more functionality, would be to create a separate `Activity` with a `Dialog theme` and put a `ListView` or whatever you need. But for what you have shown, a PopupWindow should work nicely for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'll try the PopupWindows approach ;). Anyway, isn't there any other way to take advantage of the <menu> tag <group> or <item> to make it easy?

Comment: You can `inflate` a `menu` and add items to it but you can add them to the menu resource xml after it is compiled

Comment: There is also a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) but that requires `API>=11` that you can check out and see which option is best for your needs

Comment: Well, currently I'm working with API>=11 so I'll check PoupMenu too, it seems nicer than PopupWindow and maybe fits better in my needs. Thanks again ! ;)

Comment: Yep, you have several options. It just depends on what you want/need. Glad I could help. Please accept if this works for you